# How do I use PhantomJS in Selenium in Python so my distributable is cross platform?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

So I will eventually compile to a Mac and Windows with py2app and py2exe, but I don't want to have 2 sets of source code.

Is it a solution to load one Selenium browser with "phantomjs.exe" for the windows version and the other branch of the `if` statement with a Selenium browser object with "phantomjs.dmg" (or whatever they call it on Mac).

Is that a valid solution? Is it really just as simple as giving Selenium a different browser executable?